# How to use ParamConverter with Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I know I'm probably missing something really easy, but I just don't know what, and I'm still pretty new to symfony.

I'd like to have a url like `/admin/user/edit/1234` where the controller uses the paramConverter to auto load the user from their ID.  But I keep getting an error.

```
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate url for route.
```

I tried following http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html but it's not very detailed in how it all works.

Here's my route

```
admin_edit_user:
    pattern: /users/edit/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: MyBundle:AdminUsers:editUser}
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

And here's my controller

```
<?php
//...
    class AdminUsersController extends Controller
    {
        //... 
        public function editUserAction(Request $request , User $user)
        {
            $info = $user->getInfo();

            if(is_null($info))
            {
                $info = new UserInfo();
            }

        $userInfoForm = $this->createForm(new UserInfoType() , $info , array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_edit_user')
    ));

        $userInfoForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($userInfoForm->isValid())
        {
            if(is_null($user->getInfo()))
            {
                $user->setInfo($info);
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($info);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice' , 'User Info succesfully updated.');
        }

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Admin/Users:edit.html.twig' , array(
            'user_info_form' => $userInfoForm->createView(),
            'user' => $user
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore me!  I found the issue.  When I'm generating the URL for the Form I was missing the parameters needed.

```
$userInfoForm = $this->createForm(new UserInfoType() , $info , array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_edit_user')
));
```

Needed to be

```
$userInfoForm = $this->createForm(new UserInfoType() , $info , array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_edit_user' , array('id' => '1234'))
));
```